# Blocking request using aiohttp

Tags: python-3.x, server, aiohttp

Please check the below script (python3 -m main), when I run http://0.0.0.0:8080/run1 in two different tabs parallelly. The request2 starts only after request1 ends. Each new request is blocked by the previous request. 
Any help is appreciated.

```
from aiohttp import web
import random
import time
from datetime import datetime


async def f1(request):
    res_text = "Starting count for name" + str(random.randint(1, 1000))
    res_text += "\n"
    res_text += str(datetime.now())
    res_text += "\n"
    for i in range(10):
        res_text += f"Value {i}"
        res_text += "\n"
        time.sleep(1)
    res_text += str(datetime.now())
    return web.Response(text=res_text)

app = web.Application()
app.router.add_get('/run1', f1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(app)
```

Updated the request based on suggestions:

```
from aiohttp import web
import random
import time
from datetime import datetime
import asyncio

async def f1(request):
    res_text = "Starting count for name" + str(random.randint(1, 1000))
    res_text += "\n"
    res_text += str(datetime.now())
    res_text += "\n"
    for i in range(10):
        res_text += f"Value {i}"
        res_text += "\n"
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    res_text += str(datetime.now())
    return web.Response(text=res_text)

app = web.Application()
app.router.add_get('/run1', f1)

async def start_app():
    runner = web.AppRunner(app)
    await runner.setup()
    site = web.TCPSite(runner)
    await site.start()
    return runner, site

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
runner, site = loop.run_until_complete(start_app())
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt as err:
    loop.run_until_complete(runner.cleanup())

loop.close()
```

Comment: The issue here is `time.sleep(1)` which is a blocking call; with an async framework like aiohttp you need to use async libraries as much as possible. In this case you would need **await asyncio.sleep** instead of **time.sleep**.

Comment: @IonutTicus Hi, I changed the time.sleep to  await asyncio.sleep(1). But still the req2 starts only after req1 ends. Req1: output ```Starting count for name996
2020-05-11 11:18:06.991487
Value 0
2020-05-11 11:18:17.022582``` and Req2 output
```Starting count for name139
2020-05-11 11:18:17.024334
Value 0
2020-05-11 11:18:27.054835```

Comment: If you're using a single browser and trying the same URL the browser will recognize that you are trying to load the same page in two different tabs and delay the second request until the first has finished. Try adding a parameter like `x=random_number` to the URLs or use separate browsers or something like curl/wget.

Answer (score 2):

This was surprisingly hard to pin down, but it turns out run_app is blocking. The [documentation](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_reference.html#aiohttp.web.run_app) is a bit vague about this, but on another page it calls it out explicitly as a blocking [process](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_advanced.html#application-runners). The documentation has quite bit on different ways you can serve the app in production that would be better.

**Edit:** a secondary point from the comments: sending requests from different tabs will not be recognized as different sources,so this won't work the way expected. If however you use an incognito tab it will work. If you do this with the original example with run_app (1 tab normal, 1 incognito) you will see that it is still blocking. If you use the AppRunner of the second example with the two tabs (1 tab normal, 1 incognito) you will see it is no longer blocking. If you use the AppRunner with two tabs in the same browser session then it will be blocking.

Comment: Agreed. Tried searching for other ways. The documentation is difficult to understand. Can you point to some resources for server applications

Comment: The second link in my answer suggests using AppRunner, which might work for you. Otherwise the deployment page in the docs has some options: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/deployment.html

Comment: I am using apprunner now. Request from the same browser is getting blocked. Is there any such limitations.

Comment: added some detail, but for me your app runner solution works... if you use an incognito tab. Let me know if you find the same when you try it.